# How to use JavaFX Multi-touch events with a JFX Pane component on Linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, touch-event, multi-touch

we are trying the multitouch feature of JavaFX and it doesn't seem to work fine.

In details we have tried to intercept inside a javafx.scene.layout.Pane the events:

- onSwipeDown
- onSwipeLeft
- onSwipeRight
- onSwipeUp

Here our easiest code:

**Main.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**sample.xml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<Pane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      onSwipeDown="#handleSwipeDown"
      onSwipeUp="#handleSwipeUp"
      onSwipeLeft="#handleSwipeLeft"
      onSwipeRight="#handleSwipeRight">
    <Button onAction="#btnClick" text="Click me" />
</Pane>
```

And the **Controller.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.SwipeEvent;

public class Controller {
    public void handleSwipeDown(SwipeEvent swipeEvent) {
        System.out.println("EVENT: swipeDown");
    }
    public void handleSwipeUp(SwipeEvent swipeEvent) {
        System.out.println("EVENT: swipeUp");
    }

    public void handleSwipeLeft(SwipeEvent swipeEvent) {
        System.out.println("EVENT: SwipeLeft");
    }

    public void handleSwipeRight(SwipeEvent swipeEvent) {
        System.out.println("EVENT: SwipeRight");
    }

    public void btnClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("EVENT: Click");
    }
}
```

But the code of the handler functions is never being executed. 
We tried different version of Java (8 and 11) and the result was the same. 
The touch screen on our device works fine, we used a touch device and a standard mouse. None works, while standard SWING / AWT components seems to work fine with both.

Anyone know what could be the problem? Or have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

***************************** UPDATE 2019 07 16 - Tried with JVM properties *****************************

We have also try the sample above with the JVM options:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true 
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true
```

No effect...

*************** UPDATE 2019 09 23  - Tried with different OS and different technology ***************

We have done more tests, in details we've find out that:

1. JavaFX Multitouch events work fine in windows but not in linux
2. Multitouch events work well on linux with different tecnology. We have try with Qt Widgets basic example: [Finger Paint Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtwidgets-touch-fingerpaint-example.html)

So now we know that the problem isn't the device or the OS. We aren't able to make JavaFX Multitouch events working on linux, anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: [How to create a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have observed that swipeEvents are not always detected when the handlers are set on a node. Much better when set directly on the scene. I know this is not a solution, but maybe trying that might help you understand if the hardware is working fine and if your application is receiving any gesture event.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example in Windows 7 using a MultiTouch device and a mouse.
Using the mouse only the Click event is generated.
Using the touch all events are generated.

So I guess your touch device is working as emulated mouse and is not correctly set to act as a real touch device.

Used Java 8:

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```